# Creating multiple inputs to a ClassList

Tags: c#

So I have coded for a while I C# and learned the basics, one thing that always stops me is how I can create a class and then use a list for a user to input values.

I don't know if I'm totally off the chart with this code, the problem is that I don't understand why I can't use my newly created object of the class and add input to it. All help is appreciated

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Citizen> listOfCitizens = new List<Citizen>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfCitizens.Count; i++)
        {


        Console.WriteLine("Enter Surname for the citizen:");
        listOfCitizens.SurName.add = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Lastname for the citizen:");
        listOfCitizens.Lastname.add = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter age of the citizen:");
        listOfCitizens.age.add = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Name {Citizen.SurName} {Citizen.LastName} {Citizen.age}");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Citizen
{
    public static string SurName{ get; set; }
    public static string LastName{get;set;}
    public static int age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is that loop for?

Comment: You need to tell us what exactly is wrong with your code and solve problems one-by-one. Otherwise, it's unclear which particular issue we need to address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *list of something* is not a *something*.  Just like a basket of apples is not an apple.  You don't eat the basket, you eat an item *from* the basket.

So when you create your list:

```
List<Citizen> listOfCitizens = new List<Citizen>();
```

You would then create an *item* to add to the list:

```
Citizen someCitizen = new Citizen();
someCitizen.SurName = "Smith";
// etc.
```

And then add it to the list:

```
listOfCitizens.Add(someCitizen);
```

---

*Additionally*, your `Citizen` is a little off.  Those properties shouldn't be `static`.  Not sure why you made them that way, but you should remove the `static` keyword from everything in your `Citizen` class.

Comment: Thanks alot, i think i just did that in all haste! 
I will redo the code with your input, thanks for fast feedback!